# NodeJS Course on Udemy - Mongoose Schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

[image: Postman]

[image: Mongoose Schema]

[image: Create Tour Handler]

I'm not sure why I'm getting a fail status here. I wish I had the vocabulary to describe my problem in greater detail, but I've followed the tutorial very closely and nothing seems wrong with what I've done. Can someone please help me out? Thanks so much in advance

I followed the tutorial and I'm getting a status fail. The post includes a price, so I don't know why it's throwing an price missing error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please in the future copy-paste your code into the question instead of putting a screenshot, it makes it easier to answer

Comment: because you didn't put field `price` where its a required field in your request body of the postman.